# how to restore my saved data hashMap<String, ArrayList<List>>

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

I need to restore my saved data when i close the app but I don't know how..

this is the save method:

```
public void saveHashMap(HashMap<String, ArrayList<List>> map) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<List>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String json = gson.toJson(entry.getValue());
        Log.i(TAG, "SAVED KEY = " + entry.getKey() + " value "+ json);
        prefs.edit().putString(entry.getKey(), json);

    }
}
```

in theory I think the save method work but I don't know how to make a restore method...

I need to restore a HashMap<String, Arraylist>, it is possible?

Comment: "prefs.edit().putString(entry.getKey(), json);" -> You need to call apply() or commit() or the  value will not be saved from the editor to the SharedPreferences file...

Answer (score 0):

You can create method like: `restoreData()` and use saved data from `SharedPreferences` to restore it.

Let check link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences#getAll()

Answer (score 0):

It look like you trying to store ArrayList into preference, for that you are converting it into String values and then storing the same.

First, you need to maintain a keys so that you can fetch its coresponding values.
In this case, you need to maintain an array of keys.
Then,

Step 1:
Fetch string from preference as,

String json = pref.edit().getString(entry.getKey());

And than Step 2: convert your values string to original object forms.

ArrayList yourValue = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayaList>(){}.getType());

Give it a try, i am not sure is it work or not as unable to debug code. But TypeToken is a way to use runtime parsing. You can think about this way to get desired solution

Good luck !

Comment: Welcome, if u find a answer helpful. U can meke it accepted.